# SpringBoot Application: Can I get newest values from from application.properties without hitting '/actuator/refresh' endpoint?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, application.properties

I'm following this instruction and get the expected results. ([https://spring.io/guides/gs/centralized-configuration/#:~:text=boot%3Aspring%2Dboot%2Dstarter,localhost%3A8080%2Fmessage%20endpoint.](https://spring.io/guides/gs/centralized-configuration/#:%7E:text=boot%3Aspring%2Dboot%2Dstarter,localhost%3A8080%2Fmessage%20endpoint.))

But my question is: Do I have to hit `http://localhost:8080/actuator/refresh` every time the application.properties is updated, so that `http://localhost:8080/message` can get the newest values from application.properties file?

Also, if my application have more than one instance, then I have to hit `../actuator/refresh` on every instance?